# Detect New Day on watchOS While App Is Open

Tags: watchos

I'm currently working on my first watchOS app extension, which is based on Xcode's Multiplatform template. I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to detect a significant date change, such as the observation of midnight, when the watch app is open. However, I've been unable to find such a solution. I'd like to avoid using `Timer`s, if possible.

I'm able to observe [`UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623059-significanttimechangenotificatio) (iOS) and [`Notification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1408062-nscalendardaychanged) (macOS), but I've not found a similar notification for watchOS. What I did find in the documentation for [`WKExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/WatchKit/wkextension) are notifications that are similar to iOS app lifecycle notifications.

What I want is to update the UI of the watchOS app when it's open and a new day is observed, which `UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification` gets me on iOS. Is there a way for the watch app to observe a date change when the app is open on the watch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.NSCalendarDayChanged` on watchOS as well:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(dayChanged(_:)),
    name: .NSCalendarDayChanged,
    object: nil
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed `.NSCalendarDayChanged` being available for watchOS (watchOS 2.0+), but this is exactly what I needed.